# Grey background for ?attr/selectableItemBackground after support library update

Tags: android, background, android-support-library

I've update support library to **23.2.1** and discovered that many items got the grey background.

After an investigation, I found that we explicitly define background like `?attr/selectableItemBackground`. I suppose the issues are in support library, or we use it in a wrong way.

Here is layout for explicit background definition:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 ...
```

Here is common part of our theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="divider">@color/divider_dark</item>
    <item name="icon">@color/icons_dark</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white_transparent_50p</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@color/disabled_text_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hint_text_dark</item>

    <item name="android:divider">@color/divider_dark</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@color/icons_dark</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I will add screenshot

Comment: Define what you need and what you get :)

Comment: Basically it was white background and it is greyish now

Comment: I use 23.2.1, what is your buildTool version

Comment: ok, first of all that `selectableItemBackground` is not for layouts, it doesn't work with them. It works on some Views like Button, Text. If you don't have background on view, you can use that attr and it will have ripple on background when you touch. If you have background, then you define attr as foreground, then you will get same ripple effect (or gray background on previous APIs). So i think if you have some background on your LinearLayout, it is not related to `selectableItemBackground`. Check your parent layout, windowBackground etc...

Answer (score 1):

If a layout has beet set with `?attr/selectableItemBackground`. It mean whenever you touch the layout it visibly reacts(It shows us it is selectable).

API < 21, It will show a grayish shade.

API >= 21, it will show a beautiful ripple effect.

What I would like to suggest is set  `?attr/selectableItemBackground` as `foreground` property instead of `backgroud` property to make them work as expected. And you can have space for other background to be set on that layout.

And yes, you have to set it on required layouts manually.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Several things: 1) without touching I see a gray background; 2) Setting property to foreground didn't help

Comment: 1) It might be the Theme issue. 2) Yes, 21. It was my mistake. Edited. 3) it's not helping then it have to be Theme issue. Check the theme style properties you are using in your styles.xml and styles.xml(v21) both.

Comment: Added theme definition. Can you spot anything strange or wrong there?

Comment: Remove `<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary_dark</item>` and see if it works.

Comment: Trying, but color of it is purple and not grey

Comment: Do not ignore `styles.xml` under v21 as well.